# unwind segue not working-- using action method

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue, unwind-segue

I have a button on one view controller and want it to take me to another view controller while carrying over some user input.

I am able to build and run with no problem, but nothing happens when I click on the button.  The unwind segue just doesn't work. I'd really appreciate some help... This is my code for the initial view controller:

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    //configure this destination view controller only when save button is pressed
    guard let button = sender as? UIBarButtonItem, button === saveButton else {
        os_log("save button was not pressed, cancelling", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return
    }

    let mainGoal = mainGoalTextField.text ?? ""
    let microGoal = microGoalTextField.text ?? ""

    //set the habit to be passed on to tableViewController after the unwind segue

    habit = Habit(mainGoal: mainGoal, microGoal: microGoal)
}
```

This is my code for the second view controller:

```
@IBAction func unwindToHabitList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as?ViewController, let habit = sourceViewController.habit {

            let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: habits.count, section: 0)

            habits.append(habit)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
        }

    }
```

I connected the saveButton to the the unwind segue in the storyboard already and it still does not work.  Do you have any ideas where to go forward from here?

Comment: `unwindToHabitList` needs to be in the view controller that you are unwinding *too* i.e. your first view controller

Comment: @Paulw11 not sure I follow... I copied and pasted the unwindToHabitList to the first view view controller too and becauseI used variables undefined in this view controller, it did not work.

Comment: `source` will be the second view controller.  Is your second view controller `ViewController`?  You can't use variables that aren't defined in the destination view controller.